# moodle get feedback item

Tags: mysql, moodle

when i try get the feedback items, i receipt only the first column, why?

```
SELECT
u.firstname as "Usuario",

 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 1' THEN v.value END AS "1",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 2' THEN v.value END AS "2",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 3' THEN v.value END AS "3",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 4' THEN v.value END AS "4",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 5' THEN v.value END AS "5",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 6' THEN v.value END AS "6",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 7' THEN v.value END AS "7",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 8' THEN v.value END AS "8",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 9' THEN v.value END AS "9",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 10' THEN v.value END AS "10",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 11' THEN v.value END AS "11",
 CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 12' THEN v.value END AS "12"

FROM prefix_feedback AS f
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON c.id=f.course
JOIN prefix_feedback_item AS i ON f.id=i.feedback
JOIN prefix_feedback_completed AS fc ON f.id=fc.feedback
LEFT JOIN prefix_feedback_value AS v ON v.completed=fc.id AND v.item=i.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON fc.userid=u.id

GROUP BY u.firstname

ORDER BY u.id, i.id, i.name
```

and when i remove the group by i get all columns but on a lot of rows

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Fuj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firstname column isn't unique, group by the user id or username

```
GROUP BY u.id
```

or

```
GROUP BY u.username
```

Also the CASE statement needs an ELSE otherwise there is no value.

```
CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 1' THEN v.value ELSE 0 END AS task1,
```

Also the GROUP BY statement is used for sums and counts etc. So you are probably missing SUM or MAX ?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 1' THEN v.value ELSE 0 END) AS task1,
```

or

```
MAX(CASE WHEN i.name = 'task 1' THEN v.value ELSE 0 END) AS task1,
```